# Is it possible to force the Apple Darwin Streaming Server to send streaming over port 80?

Tags: streaming, apple, mobile-devices, rtsp

Is it possible to force the Apple Darwin Streaming Server to send streaming over port 80Is it possible to force the Apple Darwin Streaming Server to send streaming over port 80?

Background:
We have a client that connects to our streaming server over a 3G/edge network.
Which fails with a connection fail error. We can see the RTSP communitation
between the terminal (handset) and the server when they use port 80 but it fails
completely over all other ports (e.g. 554)
The current hypothesis is that the 3G/edge operator blocks traffic on other ports then 80.
Also the client reports that streaming from YouTubes Streaming Servers do work, I'm guessing
YouTubes streaming server sends the streaming data over port 80.

So would it be possible to send streaming data from port 80 on the same (which probably would conflict with the RTSP server) or a "slave" server on port 80.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course, you can.

During the initial setup can set [this](http://soundscreen.com/streaming/setup-4.gif) up (I didn't take this screenshot).

Or, thereafter, you can go to the ["Port Settings"](http://127.0.0.1:1220/parse_xml.cgi?filename=ports.html) (local address of my server, change 127.0.0.1 with yours), there you can activate the streaming on port 80.